# Match a given sequence only if not between quotes, taking escaped quotes into consideration

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I use the below regular expression to only match a *given* character sequence if it is not surrounded by quotes - that is, if it is followed by an even number of quotes (using a positive lookahead) until the end of the string.

Say I want to match the word `section` only if it is **not** between quotes:

```
\bsection\b(?=[^"]*(?:"[^"]*"[^"]*)*$)
```

[Working example on RegExr](http://regexr.com/3b6rt)

How would I extend this to take escaped quotes into consideration? That is, if I insert a `\"` between the quotes in the linked example, the results stay the same.

Comment: @vks [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/), it's a PHP project I'm working on. The tag is now added to the question.

Comment: @vks Yes, unfortunately, it might happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using pcre could [skip](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Special-Backtracking-Control-Verbs) the quoted stuff:

```
(?s)".*?(?<!\\)"(*SKIP)(*F)|\bsection\b
```

In string regex pattern have to triple-escape the backslash, like `\\\\` to match a literal backslash in the [lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). Or in a single quoted pattern double escaping it would be sufficient for this case.

```
$pattern = '/".*?(?<!\\\)"(*SKIP)(*F)|\bsection\b/s';
```

See [test at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zM1hG8/1).

Comment: I thought of same but there can be multiple `\\`,then we dont know if we have to ignore all or only the odd ones :P